# Explorer View - Onsite Behavior -> Profiles won't load with 500 error

Tags: experience-editor

Sitecore Version 8.1 Update 2

Has anyone come across an issue in the Explorer mode of the Experience Editor where the Profiles tab in the Onsite Behavior is blank and throws a 500 error in JavaScript?  This works in every environment except production which is our only scaled out multi server environment.

[image]

---

Update per request here is the error we see in the Sitecore log:

```
2432 08:26:58 ERROR Application error.
Exception: System.ArgumentNullException
Message: Null ids are not allowed.
Parameter name: userName
Source: Sitecore.Kernel
   at Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.ArgumentNotNullOrEmpty(String argument, String argumentName)
   at Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User.FromName(String userName, Boolean isAuthenticated)
   at ASP.sitecore_modules_web_experienceexplorer_controls_globalheader_ascx.__Render__control1(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at Sitecore.Web.HtmlUtil.RenderControl(Control ctl)
   at Sitecore.ExperienceExplorer.Business.Pipelines.Mvc.RenderPageExtenders.InjectExperienceExplorerControl.Render(TextWriter writer)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.ExperienceEditor.Pipelines.RenderPageExtenders.RenderPageExtendersProcessor.Process(RenderPageExtendersArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.ExperienceEditor.PageExtenderResponseFilter.GetExtendersHtml()
   at Sitecore.Mvc.ExperienceEditor.PageExtenderResponseFilter.get_ExtendersHtml()
   at Sitecore.Mvc.ExperienceEditor.Pipelines.Request.RequestEnd.AddPageExtenders.Process(RequestEndArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Routing.RouteHttpHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: Can you please provide the error from the stacktrace

Comment: It seems username is null :( are you using virtualuser to test this ?

Comment: All i'm doing is logging into Sitecore using the admin account and getting this.  There are cases where we do use virtual users in the account but the code runs fine in our Dev and QA environments.  Its just in production where it does not work.